# TFS Condition pull request from specific branch

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

There is any way to condition a pull request to come from an specific branch on Team Foundation Server 2017 ? 
We are implementing [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and we would like to enforce pull requests to master always come from develop or hotfix branches .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible to configure this with out-of-the-box features of TFS/VSTS. Default branching policies (as @Andy mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267217/274535)) can help you protect the target branches - those the pull requests address as `To` branch, but the `From` (source) branch can be any, and it is not enforced.

If you are ready to write some code to support this scenario, here is the proposed approach:

Configure TFS/VSTS to [run Azure Functions as a branching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=vsts). Your function can be as simple as checking the source branch and set the pull request status to `Failure` in case the branch is not in the list of expected source branches. Otherwise, set the PR status to `Success`.

One more useful link: [Configure a branch policy for an external service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/how-to/pr-status-policy?view=vsts). You can configure it as a required policy, thus it won't be possible to complete the PR until it is satisfied.

Answer (score -2):

You can access a feature called **[Branch Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies-overview?view=vsts)** to enforce pull requests from the specific branches.

After you set up a branch policy, you cannot directly push changes to the branch. Changes to the branch are only made through pull requests.

In you scenario you just need to [Configure branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) for `develop` and `hotfix` branches.

Comment: Downvoting because I doubt this is what the topic starter is asking about. See my answer.

Comment: We already implement branch policies , the question is how to enforce from one branch to another the commit.

Comment: @jckhan Sorry for my misunderstanding, unfortunately no such a built-in feature or policy, you can try the approach mentioned in [Yan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267823/7466674) above. And you can also submit a user voice to suggest the feature from here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services